# Matrix Decomposition of Conics

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rank, matrix-factorization

I was reading about ellipse-ellipse intersection and I came across this article:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679622/intersection-between-conic-and-line-in-homogeneous-space/867428#867428

I wrote a program that implements this method and it works, but now I'm working to understand why. I understand how $D = L^T C L$ is constructed, but I don't understand how/why the decomposition $P = D + λ L$ works. It seems that the author seems to be solving for one of the eigenvalues of $D$, but I don't immediately recognize if this is a standard method or not (i.e. if it only works for conics, or only when decomposing from rank 2 to rank 1 matrices, etc). Any reference material or help understanding the theory here is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I realized I mentioned ellipse-ellipse intersections, and the article is about conic-line intersections. To erase some of the confusion, the method of determining ellipse-ellipse intersection basically comes down to constructing a pencil of conics and with that pencil finding a pair of lines that intersect the ellipses at the same points that the ellipses intersect each other. That [article can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425366/finding-intersection-of-an-ellipse-with-another-ellipse-when-both-are-rotated) for those interested.

For clarity, here is some explanation of the conic-line problem and some of the equations from the line-conic article.

The general Cartesian equation for a conic section $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ can be rewritten as $p^TQp = 0$, where:
$$p = \left [ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \\ \end{matrix} \right ],\,\, Q = \left [ \begin{matrix} A & B/2 & D/2 \\ B/2 & C & E/2 \\ D/2 & E/2 & F\end{matrix} \right ]$$
The point $p$ is in homogeneous coordinates. Here I use the letter Q to differentiate from C which is used as a coefficient in the conic equation (the article calls this matrix C). The implicit formula for a line $ax+by+c=0$ can be rewritten as expressed as $l\cdot p = 0$ where $l = [a,b,c]$ and $p=[x,y,1]^T$ as above. Additionally, the place where a line $l=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ so defined intersects another line $g=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ can be calculated using the cross product $l \times g = q$, where $q$ is expressed in homogeneous coordinates. The method for determining the intersection of the line and general conic is given in the article mentioned originally.

In the article, the matrix $L$ is the skew-symmetric matrix such that $Lg=l\times g$. If we define $R=L^TQL$ (the article calls this matrix D), then $g^TRg=0$ is the equation of all lines that intersect $l$ at points on the conic, since $(Lg)^TQ(Lg) = 0$ (but the article says the lines are tangent to the conic). The article also says that $R$ is a degenerate conic that consists of the 2 points where the line and conic intersect (which I also don't understand).

My question is the decomposition of the matrix $R$, which should have rank 2. We construct a matrix $P=R+\lambda L$ and find a $\lambda$ to make $P$ rank 1. Then, $P=uv^T$, where $u$ and $v$ are the intersection points in homogeneous coordinates. I just don't understand how the decomposition works, why it works, and if that's a general method I can use (range of applicability).

Comment: Can you rewrite some of the equations in the question please?

Comment: @nicoguaro I rewrote the equations and added more exposition about the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found the explanation in *"Perspectives on Projective Geometry"* by Richter-Gebert.

The problem is finding a line $g$ such that $g^TRg=0$, and $R=L^TQL$ where $Q$ describes the ellipse. The transformation with $L$ makes $R$ a dual conic consisting of two points of intersection and a double line that passes through them. $R$ is also a degenerate conic, so it has rank 1 or 2. For the rank 2 case, if R is symmetric (which I think it always is) it can be rewritten as $R = uv^T + vu^T$ (up to a scalar multiple), where $u, v$ are points where the line intersects the original conic. $uv^T$ alone can describe the degenerate conic since 
$$0 = \langle g,u \rangle \cdot \langle g, v \rangle = (g^Tu)(v^Tg)= g^T(uv^T)g$$
with $\langle g, u \rangle=0$ and $\langle g, v \rangle=0$ if $u$ and $v$ are on $g$, respectively. The product $uv^T$ is rank-1, so we need to find a matrix $W$ such that $g^T(R+W)g=0$ and $(R+W)$ is rank-1. If $W$ is skew-symmetric, it will satisfy the first condition. The matrix sum then becomes:
$$R+W=\left ( \begin{matrix} a&b&d\\b&c&e\\d&e&f\end{matrix} \right )+\left ( \begin{matrix}0&\tau&-\mu\\-\tau&0&\lambda\\\mu&-\lambda&0 \end{matrix} \right )$$
Notice that $M_w\,q=w \times q$ for any vector $q$ and the vector $w=[\lambda,\mu,\tau]^T$. We now need to solve for $w$ so that $(R+W)$ is rank-1. Notice that if the line $l$ passes through $u$ and $v$, $u \times v=\alpha l$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar we can choose. If we consider the sum $uv^T-vu^T$, we can see through expanding and analyzing the elements that:
$$uv^T-vu^T = \alpha M_{u\times v}=M_{\alpha l}=\alpha M_l$$
Thus, $R+\alpha M_l = 2 uv^T$. Thus, we can then choose $\alpha$ to make $R+\alpha M_l$ rank-1. Since $L = M_l$, then we can say:
$$L^TQL+\alpha L = uv^T$$
Since $u$ and $v$ are in homogeneous coordinates, any scalar multiples don't affect the points when we project them back into $\mathbb{R}^2$.